# jQuery UI and jQuery Validation conflict

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have simple .jsp page, which uses more JavaScript libraries. On the page is one form with input field. I want to use Validation plugin for this input field and I used [this](http://icanmakethiswork.blogspot.cz/2013/08/using-bootstrap-tooltips-to-display.html) tutorial, because I use Bootstrap 2.3.2.

**test.jsp**

```
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" media="all" />
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js"></script> 

        <style>
      form { padding: 10px; padding-top: 45px;}
      .error { border: 1px solid #b94a48!important; background-color: #fee!important; }
    </style>

        <title>JSP Page</title>

    </head>

    <body>
            <form method="post" action="./Servlet" name="filter">
    <div class="input-append date" id="dateFromFilter">        
                              <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" name="dateFromFilter"
                                     data-msg-date="Set date." data-rule-date="true" data-rule-required="true" />
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
                      </div>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                        $("#dateFromFilter").attr("data-date-format", "dd/mm/yyyy");
                        $("#dateFromFilter").attr("data-date", "1/1/2014");
                        $("#dateFromFilter .span2").attr("value", "1/1/2014");
                        $('#dateFromFilter').datepicker();
                      </script>

    <div class="row">
    <button type="submit">Validate</button>
    </div>

                </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $("form").validate({

      showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {

          // Clean up any tooltips for valid elements
          $.each(this.validElements(), function (index, element) {
              var $element = $(element);

              $element.data("title", "") // Clear the title - there is no error associated anymore
                  .removeClass("error")
                  .tooltip("destroy");
          });

          // Create new tooltips for invalid elements
          $.each(errorList, function (index, error) {
              var $element = $(error.element);

              $element.tooltip("destroy") // Destroy any pre-existing tooltip so we can repopulate with new tooltip content
                  .data("title", error.message)
                  .addClass("error")
                  .tooltip(); // Create a new tooltip based on the error messsage we just set in the title
          });
      },

      submitHandler: function(form) {
          alert("This is a valid form!");
      }
  });

        </script>

    </body>
```

The problem is with line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js"></script>
```

If I delete the path to this library, behaviour of validation is expected. If I import this library, validation doesn't work and I need this library for other components.

Comment: Explain exactly what you mean by "doesn't work" as there are no known issues using jQuery Validate along with jQuery UI.

Comment: @Sparky "doesn't work" I mean that the page is submitted with invalid input value. If path to jquery ui is deleted, the form is not submitted.

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle demo of this issue.

Comment: @Sparky I would like to and had tried before I posted this answer, but jsFiddle doesn't support post request and it doesn't work. You can create simple local html file with this http://pastebin.com/EBY9LmA7 code. There is only one input field, which is used for date values and you can see how validation works. If you uncomment line 11, you can submit whatever you want, because validation doesn't work.

Comment: @Sparky Can use this http://pastebin.com/7aXVWeCQ code

Comment: You can use jsFiddle for this.  We don't care what happens after a post since we're only focused on the client-side code.

Comment: @Sparky Ok, here validation works http://jsfiddle.net/eunebk0w/3/ and here http://jsfiddle.net/eunebk0w/4/ validation doesn't work. The only one difference is in external resources where jquery ui is added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no conflict... **look at your error console.**

The problem is with how you're using the `.tooltip()` method, not with jQuery Validate or jQuery UI.

> Error:  Cannot call methods on tooltip prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'

With the `.tooltip("destroy")` removed, it starts working...

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/guL85aa5/**

Comment: Thank you. Tooltip doesn't work now, but probably i can manage with this somehow.

Comment: @Matt, it's only to demonstrate the source of the problem.  I'm sure you can get Tooltip working now that you know where to focus your efforts.